# Wind animation on Google maps. iOS

Tags: ios, swift, maps

I want to add wind animation layer on iOS Google maps. There are some applications(Windy.app, Windfinder) that have functionality like that. Are there any services that can I use?

[image]

Comment: See Help Center to find out what types of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.